# Is wp-admin/about.php required? Can i omit it from my website

Tags: wp-admin

There is a page in wordpress available by default(accessible from wp-admin), the url is as follows:

https://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/about.php

I'am considering to remove this page, or block access to it however I understand that some wp-admin resources are required for proper functioning of WP websites Hence why i want to confirm and ask whether or not I can omit wp-admin/about.php from my wordpress website?

If I dont remove it  it might be indexed by google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a page in wordpress available by default(accessible from wp-admin), the url is as follows:

Only for logged in users, like any other WP Admin URL it redirects to a login page

> I'am considering to remove this page, or block access to it however I understand that some wp-admin resources are required for proper functioning of WP websites Hence why i want to confirm and ask whether or not I can omit wp-admin/about.php from my wordpress website?

**This would be a massive mistake and extreme bad practice**, you should *never* modify the contents of the `wp-admin` or `wp-includes` folders unless you're updating WordPress. They *must* remain identical to the official WP download for the version you are running.

If these folders differ in any way, either because you added, modified, or removed files, this is seen as a security breach by many security software vendors and plugins. You should be able to delete `wp-admin` and replace it with a copy from a WP download and notice no difference.

On managed hosts, you'll find that you do not have access to these folders for security reasons.

Modifying/deleting or adding to the contents of the `wp-admin` folder is extreme bad practice and is considered sign of a security breach by many hosts and security software.

> If I dont remove it it might be indexed by google.

There is no evidence for this, and the file redirects to a login screen if you are not logged in, so Google cannot access this file.

The only way for this to happen is if you've made custom modifications to WP Admin files to allow `about.php` to be loaded without logging in. If this is the case then `about.php` being visible via Google is the least of your worries and you should put your site in maintenance mode immediately to limit the damage.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying